# Accessing pixel values OpenCV 2.3 - C++

Tags: c++, opencv

How to access individual pixels in OpenCV 2.3 using C++?
For my U8C3 image I tried this:

```
Scalar col = I.at<Scalar>(i, j);
```

and

```
p = I.ptr<uchar>(i);
```

First is throwing an exception, the second one is returning some unrelated data. Also all examples I was able to find are for old IIPimage(?) for C version of OpenCV.

All I need is to get color of pixel at given coordinates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type you call `cv::Mat::at` with needs to match the type of the individual pixels. Since `cv::Scalar` is basically a `cv::Vec<double,4>`, this won't work for a `U8C3` image (it would work for a `F64C4` image, of course).

In your case you need a `cv::Vec3b`, which is a `typedef` for `cv::Vec<uchar,3>`:

```
Vec3b col = I.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
```

You can then convert this into a `cv::Scalar` if you really need to, but the type of the `cv::Mat::at` instantiation must match the type of your image, since it just casts the image data without any conversions.

Your second code snippet returns a pointer to the ith row of the image. It is no unrelated data, but just a pointer to single `uchar` values. So in case of a `U8C3` image, every consecutive 3 elements in the data returned to `p` should represent one pixel. Again, to get every pixel as a single element use

```
Vec3b *p = I.ptr<Vec3b>(i);
```

which again does nothing more than an appropriate cast of the row pointer before returning it.

**EDIT:** If you want to do many pixel accesses on the image, you can also use the `cv::Mat_` convenience type. This is nothing more than a typed thin wrapper around the image data, so that all accesses to image pixels are appropriately typed:

```
Mat_<Vec3b> &U = reinterpret_cast<Mat_<Vec3b>&>(I);
```

You can then freely use `U(i, j)` and always get a 3-tuple of unsigned chars and therefore pixels, again without any copying, just type casts (and therefore at the same performance as `I.at<Vec3b>(i, j)`).

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I was really confused with multiple channels and how are they stored.