# Learning openCV : Use the pointer element to access cvptr2D to point to the middle 'green' channel. Draw the rectangle between 20,5 and 40,20

Tags: c, opencv

In the book learning opencv there's a question in chapter 3 :

```
Create a two dimensional matrix with three channels of type byte with data size 100-by-100 and initialize all the values to 0.

Use the pointer element to access cvptr2D to point to the middle 'green' channel.Draw the rectangle between 20,5 and 40,20.
```

I've managed to do the first part, but I can't get my head around second part. Here's what I've done so far :

```
/*
    Create a two dimensional matrix with three channels of type byte with data size 100-    by-100 and initialize all the values to 0.
    Use the pointer element to access cvptr2D to point to the middle 'green' channel.Draw `enter code here`the rectangle between 20,5 and 40,20.
*/
void ex10_question3(){
    CvMat* m = cvCreateMat(100,100,CV_8UC3);
    CvSetZero(m);   // initialize to 0.
        uchar* ptr = cvPtr2D(m,0,1); // if RGB, then start from first RGB pair, Green.
    cvAdd(m,r); 
    cvRect r(20,5,20,15);
    //cvptr2d returns a pointer to a particular row element. 

}
```

I was considering adding both the rect and matrix, but obviously that won't work because a rect is just co-ordinates, and width/height. I'm unfamiliar with cvPtr2D(). How can I visualise what the exercise wants me to do and can anyone give me a hint in the right direction? The solution must be in C.

From my understanding with interleaved RGB channels the 2nd channel will always be the channel of interest. (array index : 1,4,6..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that's the direction where the winds blow from...

First of all, the problem is the C API. This API is still present for legacy reasons, but will soon become obsolete. If you are serious about OpenCV please refer to C++ API. The official tutorials are great source of information.

To further target your question, this would be implementation of your question in C++.

```
cv::Mat canvas = cv::Mat::zero(100,100, CV_8UC3); // create matrix of bytes, filled with 0
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels(3); // prepare storage for splitting
split(canvas, channels); // split matrix to single channels
rectangle(channels[1], ...); // draw rectangle [I don't remember exact params]
merge(channels, canvas); // merge the channels together
```

If you only need to draw green rectangle, it's actually much easier:

```
cv::Mat canvas = cv::Mat::zero(100,100, CV_8UC3); // create matrix of bytes, filled with 0
rectangle(canvas, ..., Scalar(0,255,0)); // draw green rectangle
```

Edit:

To find out how to access single pixels in image using C++ API please refer to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8139210/892914

Comment: I tried this :


Mat m = Mat::zeros(100,100,CV_8UC3);
 std::vector<cv::Mat> channels(3);
 split(m,channels);
 rectangle(channels[1],Point(20,5),Point(40,20),Scalar(0,255,0));
 merge(channels,m);
 cvNamedWindow("test");
 imshow("test",m);

but I just got a black square

Comment: well, I typed my code from memory, so I might have some error there. But at first glance, I guess your problem is when defining color. `channels[1]` is one channel matrix. `Scalar(0,255,0)` is 3-channel color. Try just `Scalar(255)`.

Comment: In general - yes. But you have to consider all tradeoffs it has. In short - make prototype with C++ and if it's slow, switch to pointers. AFAIK C API wont be supported much longer, so it's better to stick to C++.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    cout<<"Chapter 3. Task 3."<<'\n';
CvMat *Mat=cvCreateMat(100, 100, CV_8UC3);
cvZero(Mat);
for(int J=5; J<=20; J++)
    for(int I=20; I<40; I++)
        (*(cvPtr2D(Mat, J, I)+1))=(uchar)(255);
cvNamedWindow("Chapter 3. Task 3", CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);
cvShowImage("Chapter 3. Task 3", Mat);
cvWaitKey(0);
cvReleaseMat(&Mat);
cvDestroyAllWindows;
```